# c# convert array type to another array type without copying and iterating

Tags: c#, casting

I am trying to decode an UTF-32 encoded string, stored as `uint[]` into a `string` type.

For this I want to use `System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetString` method. However overloads of this function take either `Byte[]` or `Byte*`. I don't mind using unsafe in this particular case (however coming from C, I am not aware of the consequences of doing so)

I figured out a way to do this by copying an entire array to another of type `byte[]` either directly or indirectly. In this question I would only like to know whether it is possible to convert `uint[]` to `byte[]` (or to `byte*`, if can't convert to `byte[]`) *without copying*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible, you should *absolutely* use the span approaches on this same question by canton7, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66982763/23354).

This answer is just to complete some information from the question, specifically:

> I don't mind using unsafe in this particular case (however coming from C, I am not aware of the consequences of doing so)

The main time this information is relevant is for when:

- spans aren't available in your target platform (or can't be used with the API you're consuming)
- you're talking to unmanaged libraries via P/Invoke

Just to add some terminology: `byte*` is an *unmanaged* pointer ("unsafe"), and `ref byte` is a *managed* pointer ("safe", relatively speaking). Spans are basically "managed pointers, plus a length"; so: a `Span<byte>` (or `ReadOnlySpan<byte>`) is broadly comparable (in unmanaged land) to a pair of `byte*` and `int` (length). The huge difference is that the garbage collector understands *managed* pointers (including tracking what they touch, and fixing them if it decides to move memory around), and **does not even look at** *unmanaged* pointers (they are just opaque native integers) - so: keeping everything *managed* avoids a lot of problems.

As a consequence, if you obtain the *unmanaged* pointer to data, it is **your job** to make sure that the data can't possibly get moved while you're using it, which would make your pointer invalid. To do this, you usually use the `fixed` keyword, i.e. (in an `unsafe` block):

```cs
uint[] data = ...
fixed (uint* u32ptr = data)
{
    // we can coerce pointers:
    byte* bptr = (byte*)u32ptr;

    // TODO: and now we can use that byte* (along with data.Length * sizeof(uint))
    // to pass to e.g. Encoding methods
    return Encoding.UTF32.GetString(bptr, data.Length * sizeof(uint));
}
```

The important thing is not to store such a pointer (`u32ptr` or `bptr` here) in such a way that it could *escape* the `fixed` block. Storing it on a field, for example. As long as you don't do *that*, you're fine: the garbage collector knows how to interpret `fixed`, and knows that it can't move `data` while the thread is inside that region; `fixed` is a very low cost way of temporarily pinning data. There is a *second* way, used for longer running requirements - usually because you're handing *managed* memory to an *unmanaged* API that then holds the pointer as a field *for longer* than the P/Invoke call(s) that you might use inside a `fixed` region - `GCHandle` with a type of `GCHandleType.Pinned` - but that should be avoided usually.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using .NET Core 2.1+ / .NET Standard 2.1+, you can use [`MemoryMarshal.AsBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.asbytes?view=net-5.0) to get a `Span<byte>` over your array, then there's an [`Encoding.GetString` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Encoding_GetString_System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Byte__) which takes a `ReadOnlySpan<byte>`.

```
Span<byte> bytes = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(uintArray.AsSpan());
string str = Encoding.UTF32.GetString(bytes);
```

As I'm sure you're aware, make sure that the endianness of your machine matches the endianness of the `UTF32Encoding` instance you're using! E.g.

```
var encoding = new UTF32Encoding(bigEndian: !BitConverter.IsLittleEndian, byteOrderMark: false);
```

Comment: `Span<T>` is only available in .NET Framework >= 5.0, which I don't have and I don't want to push on users, which I'm expecting to have .NET Framework >= 4.0

Comment: `Span<T>` is also available in .NET Core 2.1+ / .NET Standard 2.1+ -- still beyond the reach of .NET Framework, but still 3 years old! (Note that it's ".NET 5" -- ".NET Framework" is the legacy runtime, and stopped at version 4.8)

Comment: @canton7 `Span<T>` might be available, but `Encoding` lacks the useful methods, meaning: you end up having to use `fixed` on the span. NetFX does not implement netstandard2.1 and never will - only netstandard2.0, and even that is a huge hack. I totally agree that this is the right approach whenever available, though.

Comment: @MarcGravell `Encoding.GetString(ROS)` was introduced in .NET Core 2.1 as well. I never claimed any of this worked in .NET Framework, only in .NET Core 2.1+ / .NET Standard 2.1+

Comment: @canton7 yep, totally understood - I'm just commending on the OP's premise of "I don't want to push on users, which I'm expecting to have .NET Framework >= 4.0" and your comments on .NET Core 2.1/ .NET Standard 2.1; I also totally believe that we ditch netfx when possible: https://blog.marcgravell.com/2020/01/net-core-net-5-exodus-of-net-framework.html