# C# in-place cast `int[]` array to `byte[]` array

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, serialization, casting

I have an array of some type (`short[]`, `int[]`, or similar base type). I want to send it through a stream, so I need it to be `byte[]`. The standard solution seems to be creating a new `byte[]` array, and use `BitConverter`. The problem with this approach is performance and memory usage - it requires allocating all new memory, copying into the new memory, and then writing the `byte[]` to the stream.

I very much want to use the original backing memory of the `int[]` array as a `byte[]` array so I can send it in-place. I am willing to enforce the requirement that the sending and receiving system must be the same endianness, for the sake of this very obvious and very significant performance difference.

Is there some way to treat an array of `int[]` or similar, as a `byte[]` in-place?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66983061

Comment: If `Span<T>` isn't available, remember that if you are writing to a stream, you don't have to convert the entire array at once, you can do it chunk by chunk. It won't save you processing cycles but it won't cost you much in memory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use `Span<T>` (.net core 3+):

```
void Send(int[] data)
{
    ReadOnlySpan<byte> byteRef = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(data.AsSpan());
    _stream.Write(byteRef);
}
```

Comment: This is great news, thanks for the reply! I am now reading up on `Span<T>` and I will need to figure out how to convert back, at the receiver end, from `byte[]` to `int[]`. If you happen to post that before I find it, it would be appreciated.

Comment: On the receiving end, simply create another `int[]`, and a `Span<byte>` from it, and `_stream.Read()` into the span. Easy peasy.  :-D